# Join multiple table if there are multiple id store in a row

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three table in database that are skill,job_post and experience. Here, I have to join these all table.

Here I have job_post table like this :

[image]

Skill table looks like :

[image]

And experience table looks like

[image]

Now, I have to join above table.Here I have join job_post and experience table.

So I have written join query like :

```
"select * from job_post as jp 
  join experience as e on e.exp_id = jp.exp_id
  where jp.emp_id in (".$ids.")"
```

But, here multiple skill_id are inserted in job_post table so how can I join job_post table to skill table?

**Note :** What I have tried is that I have write above join query then write foreach loop of that result and take skill ids from the job_post table.Then write query that match with the skill table and print skill.

But is there any way to write query instead of doing these ?

Comment: Just do a second join. You can join more than one table in a query.

Comment: @Styphon but multiple skill stored in a job_post table so how can i join job_post table with skill table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MySQL `find_in_set` and `group_concat` to do the third join :

```
select jp.*,e.*,group_concat(s.skill)
from job_post jp 
join experience e on e.exp_id = jp.exp_id
join skill s ON(FIND_IN_SET(s.skill_id, jp.skill) > 0)
where jp.emp_id in (".$ids.")
GROUP BY jp.job_id,jp.exp_id
```

Comment: i got multiple records as per the skill. Instead of doing this can we concart skill ? so we can get single records.

Comment: thanks its working.Thanks for giving me good knowledge of mysql